# Most settings in Windows 10 Settings disappeared, leaving only "Network & Internet"

Tags: windows, windows-10

Most of my Windows 10 Settings are suddenly gone (image below). I'm not sure when exactly did this happen, as I haven't touched the settings for a while. Restart doesn't help. And I cannot check updates. Except the "Settings", the system seems to work fine. All the programs are running normally.
Any suggestions?

[image: Settings main page]

[image: In Network & Internet]

The Control Panel also works as usual (but windows 10 doesn't have all its settings accessible from Control Panel. I now cannot change screen resolution, etc.).

[image: Working Control Panel]

Comment: Is the machine connected to a AD domain?  If so then the likely explanation is a System Administrator has enforced and configured the appropriate group polices to basically disable Settings.  If you are NOT connected to an AD domain then your system files are corrupt and you should perform an in-place repair of the same version of Windows 10 you are running

Comment: If not on a domain, try DISM followed by SFC.    (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
   Also see if the system upgraded to Windows 11 on you (Windows 11 is different).

Comment: Check your system event log. Look for a service that has failed or not started properly. If found, research and see if the problem is related.

Comment: If you create a new user on your machine does is happen on the new user profile when you log in? If yes, delete your user profile after backing up your local files and re-create it.

Comment: For feedback: unfortunately, none of the above worked for me. I reinstalled the system at the end.